# `isNan` in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nan

Is there a function like `isNan` (Javascript example) for Objective-C?

I just noticed this code is causing to display `Nan %`, so I need to detect is a value is NAN so I could change it to `0`.

```
[portefeuillePercentWaarde setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%", verschilPrencentage]];
```

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate. The good news is that the other question has your answer :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719417/determine-if-nsnumber-is-nan

Comment: @e.James: not a duplicate: your link is for NSNumber, this question is for float/double.

Comment: Objective-C for float or double: `isnan(verschilPrencentage)`; Swift for floatingPointType: `verschilPrencentage.isNaN`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try just adding

```
#include <math.h>
```

and then using the standard `isnan()` function to test.

You can also use the "trick" that NaN is not equal to anything, including itself:

```
double x;

// do some operation here
x = doSomething();
if (x != x)
  printf("%g is probably NaN, it's not equal to itself\n", x);
```