# Objective-C - float checking for nan

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nan

I have a variable `float slope` that sometimes will have a value of `nan` when printed out since a division by `0` sometimes happens.

I am trying to do an if-else for when that happens. How can I do that? `if (slope == nan)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [isNan in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109257/isnan-in-objective-c)

Comment: Objective-C for float or double: `isnan(slope)`; Swift for floatingPointType: `slope.isNaN`

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Two ways, which are more or less equivalent:

```
if (slope != slope) {
    // handle nan here
}
```

Or

```
#include <math.h>
...
if (isnan(slope)) {
    // handle nan here
}
```

(`man isnan` will give you more information, or you can read all about it in the C standard)

Alternatively, you could detect that the denominator is zero before you do the divide (or use `atan2` if you're just going to end up using `atan` on the slope instead of doing some other computation).

Comment: If I ever came across `if (foo != foo)` in some code I would let out a very audible "WTF".  `isnan` seems like a *far* more clear and readable method.

Comment: @Squeegy: to someone who is familiar with floating point, they read the same.  To someone who isn't, yes, `isnan` is much more clear.

Comment: `isnan(x)` defines to `x!=x` on iOS, so you are doing the exact same thing in both examples. Just a heads up for people wondering what is the best option.

Comment: @AndrewHeinlein: not exactly.  It expands to `x != x`, unless you're compiling with -ffast-math or similar, in which case it expands to a call to `__isnanf` or `__isnand` (because `x != x` won't work properly under -ffast-math).  So it's generally best to use `isnan`.

Comment: But, what does `__isnanf` and `__isnand` expand to?

Comment: @AndrewHeinlein they don't expand to anything, they are function calls.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei because NaN is defined to be not equal to anything, including NaN.

Answer (score 36):

Nothing is equal to `NaN` — including `NaN` itself. So check `x != x`.

Answer (score 7):

```
 if(isnan(slope)) {

     yourtextfield.text = @"";
     //so textfield value will be empty string if floatvalue is nan
}
else
{
     yourtextfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",slope];
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, you need to do `slope.isNaN` to check whether it is a NaN.