# How to check for NaN value in Objective-C (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cgfloat

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Objective-C - float checking for nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471988/objective-c-float-checking-for-nan)
>   [Determine if NSNumber is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719417/determine-if-nsnumber-is-nan)

I have a problem with NaN values in CGFloat, how can I check if the number is valid?

the only way so far that works is:

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", output] isEqualToString:@"nan"]) {
    output = 0;
}
```

which is not a nice solution at all! :) ... and I am pretty sure that there is something else I should do instead.

Comment: I believe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471988/objective-c-float-checking-for-nan) has the answer to your problem.

Comment: A chain of dupes, even: [Objective C - float checking for nan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471988/objective-c-float-checking-for-nan) to [isNan in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109257/isnan-in-objective-c) to [Determine if NSNumber is NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719417/determine-if-nsnumber-is-nan)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

There is a define for checking if a number is nan inf etc in math.h (you can use it without import I think).

```
isnan(myValue)
```

if you follow the define you will end up with

```
(x!=x)
```

there are also some other useful defines like isinf, [isnormal](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/numeric/math/isnormal) , [isfinite](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/numeric/math/isfinite) , ...