# App crashes on iPhone7 only: Fatal Exception: CALayerInvalidGeometry CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash

My app works perfect on iPhone6 but when I tested it on iPhone7 it crashes when I try to adjust points to an image.

> Fatal Exception: CALayerInvalidGeometry
>   CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]

```
- (void)adjustPointsToFaceModel {

FaceFeatures *features = self.faceFeaturesModel.features;

CGRect featurePointsBox = [self.view featuresBoundingBox];

[self.view.featurePointsMapping enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber* key, FeaturePointView* view, BOOL *stop) {
    FaceFeaturePoint feature = key.unsignedIntegerValue;
    CGPoint pointCenter = [self.view convertPointFromImage:[features coordinatePointForFeature:feature]];

    if (pointCenter.x < CGRectGetMinX(featurePointsBox)) {
        pointCenter.x = CGRectGetMinX(featurePointsBox);
    }
    if (pointCenter.y < CGRectGetMinY(featurePointsBox)) {
        pointCenter.y = CGRectGetMinY(featurePointsBox);
    }
    if (pointCenter.x > CGRectGetMaxX(featurePointsBox)) {
        pointCenter.x = CGRectGetMaxX(featurePointsBox);
    }
    if (pointCenter.y > CGRectGetMaxY(featurePointsBox)) {
        pointCenter.y = CGRectGetMaxY(featurePointsBox);
    }
    view.center = pointCenter;
}];

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

XCode says

> Last Exception Backtrace (0)

at

```
[self.view.featurePointsMapping enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber* key, EMFeaturePointView* view, BOOL *stop) {
```

Spent weeks on this. Any help is welcome!

Comment: This thread may be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867968/calayerinvalidgeometry-reason-calayer-bounds-contains-nan-0-0-nan-nan-cr?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add a check to make sure that the featurePointsBox rect doesn't contain any NaN values.

See the following thread:
[how to check for NaN value in Objective-C (iphone sdk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220798/how-to-check-for-nan-value-in-objective-c-iphone-sdk)