# How to use NaN in conditional breakpoints?

Tags: xcode, conditional-breakpoint

I'm trying to set a conditional breakpoint in Xcode. I want it to break if a float variable is NaN. Unfortunately  Xcode is choking on `NAN` (seems to be a compiler tag). How can I test for NaN in the condition of a breakpoint?

Answer (score 5):

I did a little more research and found that instead of using of using a conditional breakpoint, it's better to include a condition in the code and set a breakpoint on a statement within the conditional's braces.

So in my case, the code would look like

```
if (var != var) {
  NSLog(@"[Schwarzenegger accent] It's not a number");
}
```

and the breakpoint would be set on the `NSLog` line.

Instead of `(var != var)`, one can alternatively use `(isnan(var))`, but you may need `#import <math.h>`.

### References

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/989815/1431728
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3472014/1431728