# Why is percentage UILabel showing 'nan%'

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, nan, uistepper

At the moment, the app itself records cues in a certain sports match. It captures the information by updating through the `UIStepper` which will update the `UILabel`'s to 1, 2, 3... etc.

However, when I press 'minus' on the `UIStepper` to change the `UILabel` back to zero, the `UILabel` on the right side of the `UIStepper` that shows the percentages of the cues displays 'nan%' Please see the attached picture.

[image]

Why does it do this?

**Code for the percentage labels**

```
self.smashPercentageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%",([self.smashLabel.text floatValue]/self.rallies)*100];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if nan you can use a 
`isnan()` method.

And then if it is a nan then simply `yourVar = 0;`

example:

```
double test = NAN;
if(isnan(test))
    NSLog(@"YES, it is a NAN!");
```

EDIT:

```
if(isnan([self.smashLabel.text floatValue]))
       self.smashPercentageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:@"0%"];
else
       self.smashPercentageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%",([self.smashLabel.text floatValue]/self.rallies)*100];
```

this should do the trick, if not try to change `floatValue` to `doubleValue`

Comment: Sorry, how can I implement that? I'm unsure. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what your code look like, but simple example: double test = NAN;
    if(isnan(test))
        NSLog(@"YES, it is a NAN!"); So you have to pass a value (your nan from UILabel) to if(isnan(value_from_ui_label)) and then you can handle action on it. I've just edit my answer. Up there code looks cleaner.

Comment: Hey SimpleMan, I have posted the code that updates one of the percentage labels. How can I change the nan to '0'? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I just tried that and it is still showing 'nan%' in the percentage label on the right of the UIStepper. I placed a breakpoint on it too and it is just going to else and missing the '0%' part. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Strange.. maybe try second solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109257/isnan-in-objective-c .. but first should work. Have you try with double?

Comment: It looks like it will relate to what I'm trying to do with mine, but I'm not too sure how to approach it :/ I did try with double, unfortunately it was unsuccessful. I also tried it with is(isnan([self.smashPercentageLabel.text...])) but that did not work either...

Answer (score 1):

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i%%",averageValue] ;`

To show percentage with value :)