# NSDecimalNumber overflow when trying adding value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I have to add decimal values after converting them from NSString, but it fails for null values, even if I do the test.

```
[lastPrice decimalNumberByAdding:actualPrice==nil?nullValue:actualPrice]]
```

In debug mode :

```
lastPrice = 0;
actualPrice = NaN
nullValue = 0;
```

I expected that

```
actualPrice==nil?nullValue:actualPrice
```

would be estimated correctly but nil is not NaN...

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok !
The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719417/determine-if-nsnumber-is-nan)

The test should be :

```
[lastPrice decimalNumberByAdding:isnan([actualPrice doubleValue]?nullValue:actualPrice]]
```